# Getting Bower to like proxy firewalls

Tags: git, proxy, ntlm, bower

We have a corporate proxy (NTLM) that wants username, password, as well as user-agent strings.

OK, I have the strangest method that works.I would really like a global bowerrc so that I don't have to do all of this.

All I want is some clue as to why I need all of this.

Bowerrc:

```
{
 "proxy" : "http://localhost:3128",
 "https-proxy" : "http://localhost:3128",
 "strict-ssl": false,
 "user-agent": "node/v0.10.4 darwin x64"
}
```

Where localhost:3128 is my CNTLM proxy server that adds the username and password for the NTLM. (http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/ )

I also hacked the global gitconfig since I found that if I did not do this git was failing (using msygit)

```
[http]
    proxy = http://localhost:3128
    sslVerify = false
[https]
    proxy = http://localhost:3128
[url "http://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

But even weirder was that had to make CNTLM not go direct to our corporate proxy at gw6..com

But had to have it pass to fiddler (found this out by watching traffic with fiddler) and then go out.

(fragment of CNTLM)

```
PassLM          EB041709836A3284A55327B32B6B6DB0
PassNT          AABCB73697E735D9555CAFAC7F1C7E18

#Proxy      gw6.us.com:3128
Proxy       localhost:8888
```

Comment: I understand the bower and git parts. What is the PassLM and PassNT values in fragment of CNTLM? Why are you commenting out proxy that points to your corporate's url?

Comment: Passlm & passnt, we need a password for our firewall. Port 8888 is for fiddler, I had to also pass the request ther to add a user agent

Comment: This worked for me. Upvoted you.